# Greatest possible symmetry group of Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, group-theory, fermions

I have two very specific questions regarding the symmetry group of a lagrangian.

1. **N Complex Scalars, massive, non-interacting**

   Do we have a global $U(N)$ symmetry, or a global $O(2N)$ symmetry?
2. **1 Fermion, Massless, non-interacting**

   I have the idea that the symmetry group should be $U(1) \times U(1)_{chiral}$, but my teacher says its $U(2)$. Which one is correct? If it's the second one, an explicit proof would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

In the scalar field case, the Lagrangian is given by:
$$\mathcal{L} = \sum_{i=1}^N  \frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu} \bar{\Phi}_i\partial^{\mu} \Phi_i + m^2 \bar{\Phi}_i \Phi_i $$
It has a $U(N)$ symmetry under the transformation:
$$\Phi'_i = \sum_{i=1}^N  U_{ij} \Phi_j, \quad U\in U(N)$$
If we write the scalar field in terms of their real and imaginary components
$$\Phi_i  = \phi_{i} + i \phi_{i+N}$$
The Lagrangian becomes of a $2N$-dimensional real scalar field
$$\mathcal{L} = \sum_{i=1}^{2N}  \frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu} \phi_i\partial^{\mu} \phi_i + m^2 \phi_i \phi_i $$
The Lagrangian has an $O(2N)$ symmetry under:
$$\phi'_i = \sum_{i=1}^{2N}  O_{ij} \phi_j, \quad O\in O(2N)$$
Since it is the same Lagrangian, then it must have both symmetries. The difference between the two cases, is that the first transformation does not mix between the real and imaginary components of the fields, while the second does. Clearly, the second case includes the first: $U(N)\subset O(2N)$. In fact the $U(N)$ matrix can be written in the $SO(2N)$ basis as:
$$O_U = \begin{pmatrix}\operatorname{Re}U & -\operatorname{Im}U\\ 
\operatorname{Im}U & \operatorname{Re}U \end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore the answer to the first question is $SO(2N)$.

*The second question*

A single specie Dirac theory has no internal symmetries (It has Lorentz symmetry and the massless case, a conformal symmetry, but these are space time symmetries.). However at a fixed momentum, it does have an internal symmetry. The symmetry for a massive fermion is $U(2)\times U(2)$. The symmetry is due to the fact that there the spectrum includes two degenerate positive eigenvalues and two negative ones. However, in the massless case, the symmetry is indeed reduced to $U(1) \times U(1) $, because there are no right handed negative energies and left handed positive energy solutions of the Weyl equation.

*Details*

The Dirac Hamiltonian:

$$H(\mathbf{p})= c \mathbf{\alpha} \cdot \mathbf{ p} + \beta m c^2$$
Can be exactly diagonalized for a given $\mathbf{p}$ by means of the unitary transformation
$$U_{\mathbf{ p} } =  \exp \left ( \frac{\mathbf{\alpha} \cdot \mathbf{ p} }{| \mathbf{ p}|} \tan^{-1} \frac{| \mathbf{ p}|}{mc}\right )$$
Thus
$$ H(\mathbf{p})= U_{\mathbf{ p} } \begin{pmatrix}E_{|\mathbf{ p}|}  & & & \\ & E_{|\mathbf{ p}|}  & & \\ & & - E_{|\mathbf{ p}|} &\\ &  & & - E_{|\mathbf{ p}|} \end{pmatrix} U_{\mathbf{ p} }$$
With
$$ E_{|\mathbf{ p}|} = \sqrt{| \mathbf{ p}|^2 + m^2 c^4}$$
Thus the Hamiltonian is invariant under the unitary similarity transformation given in the block form
$$ U = U_{\mathbf{ p} } \begin{pmatrix}A & 0 \\0 & B\end{pmatrix}U_{\mathbf{ p} }^{-1}$$

With both $A,B \in U(2)$. This the symmetry is $U(2)\times U(2)$
In the massless case, the eigenvectors corresponding to left and right chiralities decouple and we are left with $U(1)\times U(1)$ each.

Comment: I thought the massless fermions had a larger symmetry than the massive? Your answer seems to imply the opposite. What am I missing?

Comment: If you are talking about conformal symmetries. They are not internal, since they transform space time also. I considered only rigid symmetries.

Comment: no not talking about conformal. I was recently taught that massive ones do not have the chiral symmetry so exhibit only U(1), while the massless ones respect chiral transformations and have U(2).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying that without spacetime transformations, massive fermions have a larger symmetry than massless. I can't reconcile these two ideas. Help?

Comment: You are correct. I shouldn't have called this symmetry vector or chiral, because for the massive case it mixes between chiralities. I'll correct that. I want to emphasize that a single specie of Dirac or Weyl fermion does not have internal symmetry, only space time symmetries. The  symmetries shown in the answer are  symmetries of the Hamiltonian matrix at a given $\mathbf{p}$. The reason I chose to consider them is because you mentioned $U(1)\times U(1)$ in your question. ...

Comment: cont. These symmetries are very important, because they are responsible for the Berry connection in the Foldy Wouthuysen transformation. Please see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2032v2

Comment: How do you mean "no internal symmetries"? We can see that a single specie of massive Dirac fermion has a U(1) symmetry from the lagrangian, right?

Comment: And this U(1) is on top of the Lorentz invariance of the lagrangian, by construction.

Comment: Again you are correct. But the symmetries that I talked of are additional to this U(1).

Comment: Ah I see. So U(1) is there for a massive fermion, ignoring spacetime symmetries. And massless ones have U(1)XU(1), as per your answer. That resolves things. Thanks a bunch, David!